# What did the proof by diagonalization actually disprove?

Tags: automata

http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/theory-bk/theory-bk-fourse5.html

I sort of understand the proof, but is it showing that some language are undecidable? If so, what language exactly? Because each row represent different language, ex row 1 is L1, which represent whether a string Si is accepted by M1, row 2... M2 and so on, and the diagonal is the language such that the string Si is accepted Mi.

Now, what language is shown to be undecidable?

Comment: Which proof? The link you provided contains several proofs. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

In your link, the diagonal describes a language. Notably, it defines the language $L$ that contains $x_{i}$ if and only if machine $M_{i}$ does not accept $x_{i}$.

This language $L$ is undecidable. To see why, note that if it were decidable, there would be some machine that decides it. This machine would be $M_{i}$ for some $i$ (since our list of machines contains all possible machines). But if $M_{i}$ accepts $x_{i}$, then $x_{i}$ isn't in our language, and vice versa, so we $M_{i}$ can't decide $L$, and we have a contradiction, and thus $L$ is undecidable.

Comment: Ok, I had a question similar to this, but when I checked the answer they didn't use the matrix. When they ask us to prove by diagonalization can we just draw the matrix where the diagonal represent L and row_i represent the decider that outputs the opposite values like they did?